# Unable to get search result in the list. c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EmployeeDataDataContext con = new EmployeeDataDataContext();
    List<Employee> employees = (from s in con.Employees 
                                where s.Name.ToLower() == SearchBox.Text.ToLower() 
                                select s).ToList();
    EmployeeGrid.ItemsSource = employees;
}

private void Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Employee selected = EmployeeGrid.SelectedItem as Employee;
    if (selected == null)
        MessageBox.Show("You must select the employee.");
    else
    {
        EditEmployee employee = new EditEmployee(selected);
        employee.ShowDialog();
    }
 }
```

could not getting anything in the list wheni press the search button .

Comment: Show the full `button_click` event. Do you have a click event on that button?

Comment: any exceptions? does Context contain any record that You try to find?

Comment: 'private void Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Employee selected = EmployeeGrid.SelectedItem as Employee;
            if (selected == null)
                MessageBox.Show("You must select the employee.");
            else
            {
                EditEmployee employee = new EditEmployee(selected);
                employee.ShowDialog();
            }
         }'

Comment: @ZohaibAkbar Please edit the question with updated information rather than posting to a comment.

Comment: what should i do i am  new  here.

Comment: you're doing an exact search only?  Are you typing in the exact string that you want?

Comment: Can you show use an example of what is in your DB and what you have typed into the search box?

Comment: I don't want the exact what i type i want to search like what i type

Comment: That's your problem...s.Name.ToLower() == SearchBox.Text.ToLower() is going to return only exact matches.

Comment: So you wan the equivalent of `Name like '%SearchBoxText%'` in SQL?

Comment: i want to search an employee by name from the table "employee"

Comment: Right, but if you type in "ob" should it match "Bobby" and "Rob", or just say "Oberman"?

Comment: yes exactly. search like what is type in SearchBox from the table employee column Name

Comment: yeah exactly if I type Ali it should search Ali Ahmad, M Ali,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do an partial match.  You can use `string.Contains` for that

```
where s.Name.ToLower().Contains(SearchBox.Text.ToLower())
```

That will allow your text to match anywhere within the name column.

Comment: are you there i need to ask another question.

Comment: @ZohaibAkbar If you need to ask another question then you should just post a new question on SO.